# gitlab-ci docker-in-docker with unsecure registry

Tags: gitlab, docker-swarm, gitlab-ci-runner

I currently try to deploy an image build on a gitlab ci/cd to registry.

`runner` and `gitlab` containers are setup into the `gitlab` network. 
Therefore, I couldn't make it work.

Here are my configs :

```
# gitlab-runner.toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "runner1"
  url = "http://gitlab"
  token = "t4ihZ8Tc4Kxy5i5EgHYt"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    host = ""
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ruby:2.1"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    shm_size = 0
    network_mode = "gitlab"
```

```
# gitlab.rb
external_url 'https://gitlab.domain.com/'
gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = File.read('/run/secrets/gitlab_root_password')
nginx['listen_https'] = false
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = false
letsencrypt['enable'] = false

gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] ="smtp.domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "password"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'

gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@domain.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'noreply@domain.com'
```

```
# gitlab-compose.yml
version: "3.6"
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    volumes:
      - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
      - gitlab_logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
    shm_size: '256m'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: "from_file('/omnibus_config.rb')"
      GITLAB_ROOT_EMAIL: "contact@domain.com"
      GITLAB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
    configs:
      - source: gitlab
        target: /omnibus_config.rb
    secrets:
      - gitlab_root_password
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.role == compute
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
        - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
        - "traefik.http.services.gitlab.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.rule=Host(`gitlab.domain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.gitlab.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt"
    networks:
      - gitlab
      - traefik-public

configs:
  gitlab:
    file: ./gitlab.rb
secrets:
  gitlab_root_password:
    file: ./root_password.txt
volumes:
  gitlab_data:
    driver: local
  gitlab_logs:
    driver: local
  gitlab_config:
    driver: local
networks:
  gitlab:
    external: true
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

```
#gitlab-ci
stages:
  - gulp_build
  - docker_build_deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

variables:
  DEPLOY_USER: $DEPLOY_USER
  DEPLOY_TOKEN: $DEPLOY_TOKEN

build app:
  stage: gulp_build
  image: node:14.17
  before_script:
    - npm install
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build -production
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public

docker deploy:
  stage: docker_build_deploy
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      command: ["--insecure-registry=gitlab"]
  before_script:
   - docker login -u $DEPLOY_USER -p $DEPLOY_TOKEN gitlab
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - docker build -t gitlab/laurene/domain.com:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG -t gitlab/laurene/domain.com:latest .
    - docker push gitlab/laurene/domain.com:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - docker push gitlab/laurene/domain.com:latest
```

Deployment logs :

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 14.9.1 (bd40e3da)[0;m
[0K  on runner1 t4ihZ8Tc[0;m
section_start:1650242087:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image docker:latest ...[0;m
[0KStarting service docker:dind ...[0;m
[0KPulling docker image docker:dind ...[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:a072474332af3e4cf06e349685c4cea8f9e631f0c5cab5b582f3a3ab4cff9b6a for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:210076c7772f47831afaf7ff200cf431c6cd191f0d0cb0805b1d9a996e99fb5e ...[0;m
[0KWaiting for services to be up and running...[0;m

[0;33m*** WARNING:[0;m Service runner-t4ihz8tc-project-2-concurrent-0-2cd68d823b0d9914-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.

Health check error:
service "runner-t4ihz8tc-project-2-concurrent-0-2cd68d823b0d9914-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout

Health check container logs:


Service container logs:
2022-04-18T00:34:50.436194142Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2022-04-18T00:34:50.490663718Z ............++++
2022-04-18T00:34:50.549517108Z ...............++++
2022-04-18T00:34:50.549802329Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2022-04-18T00:34:50.562099799Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2022-04-18T00:34:50.965975282Z .....................................................................................................................++++
2022-04-18T00:34:51.033998142Z ..................++++
2022-04-18T00:34:51.034281623Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2022-04-18T00:34:51.056355164Z Signature ok
2022-04-18T00:34:51.056369034Z subject=CN = docker:dind server
2022-04-18T00:34:51.056460584Z Getting CA Private Key
2022-04-18T00:34:51.065394153Z /certs/server/cert.pem: OK
2022-04-18T00:34:51.067347859Z Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
2022-04-18T00:34:51.210090561Z ........................................++++
2022-04-18T00:34:51.491331619Z .................................................................................++++
2022-04-18T00:34:51.491620790Z e is 65537 (0x010001)
2022-04-18T00:34:51.509644008Z Signature ok
2022-04-18T00:34:51.509666918Z subject=CN = docker:dind client
2022-04-18T00:34:51.509757628Z Getting CA Private Key
2022-04-18T00:34:51.519103998Z /certs/client/cert.pem: OK
2022-04-18T00:34:51.594873133Z ip: can't find device 'ip_tables'
2022-04-18T00:34:51.595519686Z ip_tables              32768  3 iptable_mangle,iptable_filter,iptable_nat
2022-04-18T00:34:51.595526296Z x_tables               40960 14 xt_REDIRECT,xt_ipvs,xt_state,xt_policy,iptable_mangle,xt_mark,xt_u32,xt_nat,xt_tcpudp,xt_conntrack,xt_MASQUERADE,xt_addrtype,iptable_filter,ip_tables
2022-04-18T00:34:51.595866717Z modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
2022-04-18T00:34:51.597027030Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2022-04-18T00:34:51.597064490Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2022-04-18T00:34:51.597067880Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2022-04-18T00:34:51.597608422Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)

[0;33m*********[0;m

[0KPulling docker image docker:latest ...[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:7417809fdb730b60c1b903077030aacc708677cdf02f2416ce413f38e81ec7e0 for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:41978d1974f05f80e1aef23ac03040491a7e28bd4551d4b469b43e558341864e ...[0;m
section_end:1650242124:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1650242124:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m[0;m
Running on runner-t4ihz8tc-project-2-concurrent-0 via fed5cebcc8e6...
section_end:1650242125:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1650242125:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m[0;m
[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 20...[0;m
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/laurene/oelabs.co/.git/
[32;1mChecking out a63a1f2a as master...[0;m
Removing node_modules/

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1650242128:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1650242128:restore_cache
[0K[0K[36;1mRestoring cache[0;m[0;m
[32;1mChecking cache for default...[0;m
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted.[0;m 
[32;1mSuccessfully extracted cache[0;m
section_end:1650242129:restore_cache
[0Ksection_start:1650242129:download_artifacts
[0K[0K[36;1mDownloading artifacts[0;m[0;m
[32;1mDownloading artifacts for build app (97)...[0;m
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok      [0;m  id[0;m=97 responseStatus[0;m=200 OK token[0;m=Uvp--J3i
section_end:1650242131:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_start:1650242131:step_script
[0K[0K[36;1mExecuting "step_script" stage of the job script[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing docker image sha256:7417809fdb730b60c1b903077030aacc708677cdf02f2416ce413f38e81ec7e0 for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:41978d1974f05f80e1aef23ac03040491a7e28bd4551d4b469b43e558341864e ...[0;m
[32;1m$ docker login -u $DEPLOY_USER -p $DEPLOY_TOKEN gitlab[0;m
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
time="2022-04-18T00:35:33Z" level=info msg="Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint" error="Get \"https://gitlab/v2/\": dial tcp 10.0.18.4:443: connect: connection refused"
Get "https://gitlab/v2/": dial tcp 10.0.18.4:443: connect: connection refused
section_end:1650242133:step_script
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```

Comment: GitLab stores the registry hostname[:port] in the `CI_REGISTRY` environment variable. Replace `gitlab` with `$CI_REGISTRY` in your `docker login` command, and try again. See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#authenticate-by-using-gitlab-cicd